# Linear transformation of $5$ points in a graph.

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm taking a digital imaging processing class and my linear algebra is really rusty. I basically have $5$ points in my $5\times 2$ data matrix:

```
data = [-92/50  -8/50; 
        -1      -57/50; 
        -39/50   36/50; 
        73/50    60/50; 
        103/50   59/50];
```

I've calculated the covariance, eigenvector $2\times2$ matrix, and I have the eigen values but I don't know how to proceed from here. The book just explains that I should diagonalize the matrix to get my new x' and y' values but my original matrix wasn't square. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my question:
[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3L4H.png)

Comment: You have the eigenvectors and eigenvalues ... of what? There must be a square matrix lurking there somewhere, otherwise you wouldn't be talking about eigenvectors and eigenvalues.

Comment: I have the eigenvectors and values of my covariance matrix which is [2.8418 1.2729; 1.2729 1.0070]

Comment: Well then maybe it's the covariance matrix that you are supposed to diagonalize.

Comment: How would I transform my matrix to get my new 5 points in this new 2D dimension? I uploaded an image of my question to my original post.

Comment: Do you know how to form a basis from the eigenvectors?  Do you know how to do a general coordinate transformation?

Comment: Isn't my basis the eigenvectors as columns in a matrix? That's what I'm having trouble doing is doing the coordinate transformation.

Comment: Yes, you have to remove the mean from the data and then project the data onto your eigenvectors (i.e. basis).  If you put them in columns as $R = [v1 v2]$ then the formula is something like this: $data2 = R'*(data-mean)'$.  You will have to work out the right Matlab, but that is the jist of what you need to do.

Comment: What do you mean by removing the mean from the data? I would remove the mean from every point? Then I wouldn't be able to multiply R'*(data-mean)' because it would be a 2x2 matrix multiplied by a 5x2. If it where the other way around it would just be another 2x2 matrix.